# .Net Console Apps - Where's the exe?

Tags: console-application, exe, shortcut

I often write console apps to do jobs on the server (Win 2k8 R2)
I publish the .net console app project, then transfer the files to the server, and run the install.
I can always find the app in the start bar after a quick search.

However, I'd like to know where the actual .exe is so I can make a scheduled task to run it.
Where can I find it?

e.g.
[image]

Comment: Under Location? Or do you want to programmatically resolve a shortcut to where it points to?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using a click once installer.

Have you checked  `C:\Documents and Settings\{username}\Local Settings\Apps` (Win XP) and `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Apps` (Vista and 7)?
There should be subfolders with generic names that contains you application.

Beware that the specific path changes everytime you update the application.

Comment: I do not see it in those 2 folders, no